# Python IndexError handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def kindDetector(list):
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        if type(list[i]) != type('a'):
            return 0
    return 1

def findWords(list,i):
    if i == 0:
        return list[0]
    if list[i] < findWords(list,i-1):
        return list.pop(i)
    else:
        return list.pop(i-1)

def sortWords(list,i):
    result=[]
    while i >= 0:
        result.append(findWords(list,i))
        i -=1
    print(result)


list = input('Enter your words, with a space between.\t').split()
i = len(list)-1
if kindDetector(list):
    sortWords(list,i)
```

But here i only can enter 2 words when i try it with 3 this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/honey/Desktop/python/selfMade/sortWords.py", line 26, in <module>
    sortWords(list,i)
  File "C:/Users/honey/Desktop/python/selfMade/sortWords.py", line 18, in sortWords
    result.append(findWords(list,i))
  File "C:/Users/honey/Desktop/python/selfMade/sortWords.py", line 10, in findWords
    if list[i] < findWords(list,i-1):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: A debugging tip is to print i right before that line. Then you can see what actually goes wrong. With this error, `i` is either too large (with 3 words, larger than 2) or too small (smaller than 0). It also helps other people if you can post that value of i in your question.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're doing but I think the pb comes from the fact that is only one list in your program so when you modify it in a recursive call, it also change in others calls.

Comment: oh ok, sorry am a beginner sooo..., but thank you very much guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed *BubbleSort* (i.e. comparing neighbors and trying to shift them one at a time until the list is sorted) with *SelectionSort* (i.e. find the *smallest* item from an unsorted list and append it to the front of a resulting list).

And, there are a few more problems here:

- Python passes variables by reference, which means that your functions receive a handle for the original list instead of a copy. If you change the list (what your `pop()` calls do) while iterating, you will run into index errors.
- Your `findWords` function is flawed. You iterate from back to front and check whether the current element is lexicographically smaller than its predecessor (i.e. *left* neighbor). You probably want to change the `pop`-calls to `return` statements, don't you?

I have quickly implemented a few basic sorting algorithms (no error handling, type comparator usage etc whatsoever):

```
def is_list_of_strings(lst):
    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        if type(lst[i]) not in (str, unicode):
            return False
    return True

def is_sorted(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return True
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        if not lst[i] < lst[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True

def selection_sort(lst):
    l = lst[:] # Copy!
    r = []
    while len(l):
        r.append(l.pop(l.index(min(l))))
    return r

def insertion_sort(lst):
    l = lst[1:] # Copy!
    r = [lst[0]]
    for e in l:
        inserted = False
        for w in r:
            if e < w:
                r.insert(r.index(w), e)
                inserted = True
                break
        if not inserted:
            r.append(e)
    return r

def bubble_sort(lst):
    l = lst[:] # Copy!
    while not is_sorted(l):
        for i in range(len(l) - 1):
            if l[i] > l[i + 1]:
                tmp = l[i]
                l[i] = l[i + 1]
                l[i + 1] = tmp
    return l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = ['aaa', 'aba', 'aab', 'baz', 'bar']

    print('Valid list of strings?', is_list_of_strings(lst))
    print(lst, is_sorted(lst))

    bbl = bubble_sort(lst)
    ins = insertion_sort(lst)
    sel = selection_sort(lst)

    print(bbl, is_sorted(bbl))
    print(ins, is_sorted(ins))
    print(sel, is_sorted(sel))
```

Have a look at them, try to understand them and have a read about these three techniques online. And then try to re-implement them using your own functions. Have fun coding :)